# API Geocoding gives error on Stern taxi fare plugin for wordpress

Tags: wordpress, api, geocoding

I am using the Stern Taxi Fare plugin.
I get this error in my Wordpress dashboard:

```
-----------------------------DEBUG-----------------------------
object(stdClass)#19839 (2) {
    ["results"]=> array(0) { }
    ["status"]=> string(12) "ZERO_RESULTS"
}
-----------------------------DEBUG-----------------------------
```

API Geocoding can not connect.
How can I get this working?

Answer (score 0):

I just got mine to work! Here is how:

1. Locate the controller/stern_taxi_fare_functions.php
2. Go to line 923; 
    $url.="address=A";

   3. Change the A to Los Angeles
   4. Save and Enjoy